# Antiforgery token with Blazor .Net 8 on a web farm - machinekey not used

Tags: blazor, antiforgerytoken, web-farm

I'd like to deploy a Blazor Web App (.Net 8) on a web farm (windows + IIS).
If I deploy the app on a single machine, it works fine.
But when many servers are used with load-balancing, then an Antiforgery error is launched when accessnig pages that use antiforgery:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery - An exception was thrown while deserializing the token. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {d1a4d3f6-a151-4829-8561-e7e49e3c1341} was not found in the key ring. For more information go to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning
```

I've read this article on [Anti forgery token and manchine key](https://medium.com/drunkcoding/anti-forgery-token-and-machine-key-6cb4cc65fc73) and applied what the author suggested (it means forcing the same machine key on IIS on all servers), but unfortunately it doesn't resolve the issue.

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: can the application actually find the key d1a4d3f6-a151-4829-8561-e7e49e3c1341 in the keyring? I did a blog post about the key ring here https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en

Comment: Thank you for your blog. This is very clear.
It means that I need to store the keys in a shared place... like a Azure Key vault, or a database or a shared folder...
I'll work on this and update my post if it works.

Comment: I will post an answer here and hope you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the Data Protection Key ring in some persistent storage, like a database or as a file somewhere.

I did a blog post about how to store it in Azure Key Vault (As a learning exercise)
: [Storing the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault](https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en)

However, this is not an example of production quality. I suggest you use one of the more hardened storage alternatives as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0

The picture below shows an example of what it can look like in production and if you want to share cookies across service instances.

[image]

Comment: Thank you again. I confirm that storing the keys in a database is one of the solutions. It works both for Antiforgery and Identity !

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it answers your question :-)